# What does it mean by "a valid inclusion of one side in the other"

Tags: linear-algebra

in my homework on linear algebra, there is a question that I do not understand. The question on the worksheet is

> Let $T, U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$. (a) Give an explicit counter-example to the statement that $T + (U \cap W) = (T + U) \cap (T+W)$. (b) Show that the equality in the expression in part (a) can be replaced by a valid inclusion of one side in the other.

and I cannot understand nor can I find an explanation anywhere about the statement "valid inclusion of one side in the other". The same statement appears in another question as well. What do you think it means?

Comment: It means $A\subset B$ or the other way around, where $A$ and $B$ are the spaces on either side of the equal sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that that one of the following statements is true:

$$T+(U\cap W)\subseteq(T+U)\cap(T+W)$$

$$T+(U\cap W)\supseteq(T+U)\cap(T+W)$$

You should find out which and prove that.

Edit: I mixed up $\cup$ and $\cap$ initially.